# Integration tests for a simple Spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, integration-testing, scalatest

I need to write some unit and integrations tests for a small research project. I am using a simple Spark application which read the data from a file and outputs the number of characters in a file. I am using ScalaTest for writing unit tests. But I could not come up with the integration tests for this project. According to the project flow I need to execute unit tests, package a jar file and then using this jar file execute integration tests. I have a file with data as a resource for the tests. So should I package this file with the source code or should I put it into a separate location? What kinds of integration tests can I write for this application?

Simple Spark application looks like this:

```
object SparkExample {

  def readFile(sparkContext: SparkContext, fileName: String) = {
    sparkContext.textFile(fileName)
  }

  def mapStringToLength(data: RDD[String]) = {
    data.map(fileData => fileData.length)
  }

  def printIntFileData(data: RDD[Int]) = {
    data.foreach(fileString =>
      println(fileString.toString)
    )
  }

  def printFileData(data: RDD[String]) = {
    data.foreach(fileString =>
      println(fileString)
    )
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("TestApp")
      .getOrCreate()

    val dataFromFile = readFile(spark.sparkContext, args(0))

    println("\nAll the data:")

    val dataToInt = mapStringToLength(dataFromFile)

    printFileData(dataFromFile)
    printIntFileData(dataToInt)

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Unit tests I wrote:

```
class SparkExampleTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with Matchers{

  val master = "local"
  val appName = "TestApp"
  var sparkContext: SparkContext = _
  val fileContent = "This is the text only for the test purposes. There is no sense in it completely. This is the test of the Spark Application"
  val fileName = "src/test/resources/test_data.txt"
  val noPathFileName = "test_data.txt"
  val errorFileName = "test_data1.txt"

  before {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master(master)
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()
    sparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext
  }

  test("SparkExample.readFile"){
    assert(SparkExample.readFile(sparkContext, fileName).collect() sameElements Array(fileContent))
  }

  test("SparkExample.mapStringToLength"){
    val stringLength = fileContent.length
    val rdd = sparkContext.makeRDD(Array(fileContent))

    assert(SparkExample.mapStringToLength(rdd).collect() sameElements Array(stringLength))
  }

  test("SparkExample.mapStringToLength Negative"){
    val stringLength = fileContent.length
    val rdd = sparkContext.makeRDD(Array(fileContent + " "))

    assert(SparkExample.mapStringToLength(rdd).collect() != Array(stringLength))
  }


  test("SparkExample.readFile does not throw Exception"){
    noException should be thrownBy SparkExample.readFile(sparkContext, fileName).collect()
  }

  test("SparkExample.readFile throws InvalidInputException without filePath"){
    an[InvalidInputException] should be thrownBy SparkExample.readFile(sparkContext, noPathFileName).collect()
  }

  test("SparkExample.readFile throws InvalidInputException with wrong filename"){
    an[InvalidInputException] should be thrownBy SparkExample.readFile(sparkContext, errorFileName).collect()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark Testing Base is the way to go, - it is basically a lightweight embedded spark for your tests. It would probably be more on the "integration tests" side of things than unit tests, but you can track code coverage etc. also, eg. with scoverage
https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base